# is this jQuery post preventing to MVC3 redirect my View?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http-post

So this is my controller:

```
public class MyAccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction(int id = 1)
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection values)
    {
        return Content(values["something"]);
    }  
}
```

and this is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <input type="hidden" name="something" value="something" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

It'll work as expected, if you click the submit button it'll redirect the page and will show "something"

But when I change my View to this:

```
<button id="button">submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button").on("click", function (e) {
        $.post("/MyAccount/MyAction", {something:"something"})
    });
</script>
```

It won't return the "Content" to the browser, I've debugged the application, and it gets into my post action, but when it arrives to "return Content(values["something"]);" it doesn't do anything.

Is it jQuery somehow preventing my app to redirect the page?

Comment: What gets POSTed in Firebug?  What do you see in the FormCollection in the debugger?

Comment: Firebug shows what expected: something=something
so FormCollection will be able to retrive the "something" variable, everything seems to work perfectly, until you try to "return" something, I tried to return a hard coded string, a new View, etc. And none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as @SLaks and @bhamlin said $.post is an ajax call. And you have to handle what it gets back from the server. so this is what I did:

```
<button id="button">submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button").on("click", function (e) {
        $.post("/MyAccount/MyAction", { something: "something" }, function (data) {
            $('body').replaceWith(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.post()` is an ajax call. You have to handle the result if you want to do anything with it.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Not necessarily true, the []'s in the docs indicate that data and success are optional.

Comment: @JohnFable: Yes, but without a callback, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't do anything because you didn't tell it to do anything.
`$.post` just fetches data from your server; it doesn't display it or anything.

You need to do something with the data in the callback parameter by passing a function.

Comment: I am just going to post this comment because this actually could be a bit confusing to someone. I am fairly competent with jQuery and I totally just overlooked it. What the OP is asking for is essentially a redirect with post data, not simply an AJAX post. It is exactly what you are saying but the answer isn't 100% clear as to the behavior the OP expects and the reason it isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a semi-colon:

```
    $.post("/MyAccount/MyAction", {something:"something"})
```

Change to

```
    $.post("/MyAccount/MyAction", {something:"something"});
```

Comment: Semicolons in Javascript are optional.  Yes, really.

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, but without a semicolon, it doesn't look right. (actually, I did not know that, not that I am going to start omitting them or anything)